# How do I write Arduino readings to a file on the computer?

Tags: c, serial-port, arduino

I want to write Arduino's data readings to a file locally on the computer. I MUST do this in C for a specific reason. Also, I am working in Windows 7 not Linux.

I couldn't find any useful codes on the internet that satisfies my requirement. Can anyone help?

Comment: What connection do you have? Are you considering some form of data link? Which Arduino "data readings" are important for placement on said computer? Are you wanting to "write" these "data readings" in real time? You refer to "my requirement", what specifically is your requirement that prevents you finding something useful. I'm sorry for sounding like a spambot but, to help you, folk might need more info. And finally, how do you justify this being an EE question?

Comment: You couldn't find any serial port code examples on the web? Nothing? Amazing. Not even on the Arduino sites? I think you should look harder.

Comment: Find/write an Arduino code that outputs the readings to your computer, then write code on your computer to capture those to a file.

Comment: (Much) more information required, but. (1) The Arduino can be made to output "RS232" asynchronous serial data. There will be much on Arduino sites re thi. (2) Any WIN7 PC with USB can have an "RS232" asynchronous serial port added, and older PCs and a few newer ones have such a port already equipped. (3) There are MANY on web examples on reading a PC asynchronous serial port. Routines / functions / ... to do this will be incorporated in the C language that you are using.

Comment: My question is: please help me find one that fits my requirement as I couldn't find any. Don't assume there are a lot that do it.

Comment: The only requirements I read from your question are: Must work on Win7 and must be programmed in C. You could tell us what you have found yourself and how that doesn't meet your requirements. Also when programming on Win7 I would switch to C# or probably C++. Mind you these can be very different than C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should think about [Processing](http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Processing) it uses the same IDE as the Arduino. It has common libraries for sending data back and forth between the Arduino and host PC. Where Processing is built on Java, its code that you write looks just like that of the Arduino's C++